# Can I use HDMI 1 instead of HDMI 0?

Tags: hardware, electronics

I am using a raspberry pi 4 and I only have an adapter, so it's to big to fit in HDMI 0 is there a way I can make it work with HDMI 0?

Comment: What do you mean by HDMI 0 and HDMI 1? The Pi4 has a micro-hdmi-plug. With the correct adapter, you can attach any HDMI-capable screen.

Comment: The Pi4 has two micro HDMI sockets. I presume he has a rigid adapter and it's interfering mechanically with the USB C power cable when plugged into HDMI0.

Comment: Do you only want to use HDMI0? Seems there is typo in your question. Can you please clarify this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A fully updated Raspberry Pi 4 will boot up properly and show the desktop, regardless of which hdmi port was used.

Now I faintly remember this not being the case at some point, but Forum moderator & engineer Jamesh has [made it clear](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=266608#p1619852):

> This rumour just won't die. You only need to use Hdmi zero if you want 4kp60.

Answer (score 1):

I've not seen a way to swap HDMI 0 with 1 but there is a note towards the end of [video options](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/video.md) in Raspbian that MAY do it.

Add

```
framebuffer_priority = 7
```

to config.txt This says HDMI 1 is to be the output of the pre-KMS frame buffer.

Best thing to be honest is hunt an adapter that fits as I have no idea what will happen with application software and future drivers.

Please note I have not tried this (no Pi 4B - had to buy wallpaper) so please let us know if it works.